# how long will the python API take for the same query compared with c/c++?

Tags: dolphindb

I would like to ask, for the same back-end ddb, if the query result is 1G, how long will the access time with Python increase compared to using c/c++? I don't know if there is any test in this area.

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB has optimized the Python API, and the underlying C++ language is also used, using the pickle protocol. If the data type does not contain a string, it is almost the same. If it contains a string, the time may increase by about 30%.